# Getting custom settings values from apex to lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

I am trying to get the field defualt values form a custom setting into lwc.

One of my field names is empty case id, i have more within this setting just not in the screen shot. I'm trying to get the default value for each field to be used in lwc. How can this be done, for now when i do a console.log i get undefined.

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static Timesheet_Settings__c getCustomSettings(){
    return Timesheet_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
}
```

.js

```
 @wire(getCustomSettings)
    timesheetCustomSettings;
```

custom setting
[image]

console output

```
assignSettings() {
    console.log(this.timesheetCustomSettings.data.Empty_Case_ID__c;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show code where you are doing console.log?

Comment: within a function
assignSettings() {
    console.log(this.timesheetCustomSettings.data.Empty_Case_ID__c;
}

Comment: I can't see please update code here

Comment: i have updated the initial post, at the bottom

Comment: Try debugging this.timesheetCustomSettings.data only and see if anything is coming. Also add debug in apex to see anything is returning from there or not

Comment: Also from where you are calling that assignSettings function?

Comment: outpuing this.timesheetCustomSettings.data returns [Object object], and the assignsettings is called within a wired function.

Comment: Try debugging like console.log(JSON.stringify( this.timesheetCustomSettings.data)) and see if there any field Empty_Case_ID__c coming?

Comment: nope just getting undefined returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your function like this and see if you are getting anything -

```
    assignSettings() {
        if(this.timesheetCustomSettings.data){
           console.log(this.timesheetCustomSettings.data.Empty_Case_ID__c);
        }  
    }
```

If this is not working add debug in your apex class as well and see if anything is returning from it.If not check any default data is set or not

Step-
Open custom setting. Click on manage button. On top you can see Default Organization Level Value. There will be new button on top of it. Click on new and add default data and then you will be good to go.

Comment: This returns undefined on console, where should i add debug in the apex method?

Comment: Can you please do  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.timesheetCustomSettings.data)) and add screenshot what you are getting in console. Because it can not be undefined as it is going inside if condition

Comment: console is just outputting {}. Debug in the apex is also returning {}

Comment: see the bottom of the initial post, i have included the empty case id setting, is that setup correctly?

Comment: If no custom setting data is defined for the organization it will return null

Comment: where do i add the custom setting data? sorry this is first time using custom settings

Comment: i thoguht the default value would be used

Comment: Open custom setting. Click on manage button. On top you can see Default Organization Level Value. There will be new button on top of it. Click on new and add default data and then you will be good to go.

Comment: omg simple as that lol, thank you appreciate the help :)

Comment: Happy to help. Keep coding